# How to exit tmux without leaving my terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

I'm using tmux on bash, and letting it start automatically from `.bashrc`. Sometimes I want it disabled, and I should edit my `.bashrc` to do so. Editting a file everytime I disable tmux is quite troublesome, and I think the easiest way to do the same thing is exiting tmux without leaving terminal. Can I do that?

When I type `exit`, bash and terminal close. I tried `exec bash` , but it just restarted bash inside tmux.

I start tmux from code below, according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Bash.

```sh
if [[ $DISPLAY ]]; then
        # If not running interactively, do not do anything
        [[ $- != *i* ]] && return
        [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
fi
```

If I just run `tmux` in code above instead of `exec tmux`, I can achieve my goal. But I don't like that, because I don't understand why the code uses `exec tmux` rather than `tmux` and don't wanna change it rashly, and when I run `tmux` I shoud type `exit` or `C-d` twice in order to exit terminal.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to just remove the `exec`; using it causes `tmux` to *replace* the shell sourcing `.bashrc`, and that is precisely what you do *not* want to do.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I'm gonna remove `exec`, and that resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: this question should really be on `unix.stackexchange.com`). One simple solution is to replace the line

```
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

with

```
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && { tmux; [ ! -f ~/dontdie ] && exit || rm ~/dontdie; }
```

This runs tmux as before, but when it exits goes on to test for the existence of a file, `~/dontdie`. If the file does not exist the `&& exit` is done and the terminal closes as before.  If, however, you create the file before leaving tmux, then you will do the `|| rm ...` part, which removes the file, and continues through the rest of the `.bashrc` file, leaving you in the bash shell.

So, to stay in the terminal, from the tmux window you type the commands:

```
touch ~/dontdie; exit
```

instead of just `exit`, and you will exit tmux and continue in bash.
To make it easier you can add a binding in `~/.tmux.conf` to a key, such as `X`:

```
bind-key X send-keys 'touch ~/dontdie; exit' Enter
```

Then you simply type your prefix character, Control-B by default, then X to create the file and exit tmux.

Comment: Except for using `tmux`, this works perfectly. In fact, what are the proc & cons of `exec tmux` and `tmux`?

Comment: When you `exec tmux` you replace the shell process by tmux. When tmux exits, you cannot go back to the shell, and have to go back to whatever started the shell, if it is still running. You do not continue with the lines in `.bashrc` that follow the exec.   Without the exec, when tmux exits you do continue with those lines, and when the shell gets to the end of the `.bashrc` file, it continues in your terminal.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using `tmux` rather than `exec tmux`, and vice versa? I feel awkward using `tmux`, because I don't understand why the reference uses `exec tmux`. Is there no quite reason to choose `exec tmux` than `tmux`?

Comment: If it helps to understand, you could replace `exec tmux` by `tmux; exit`, which has the same effect. The value of using exec in this case is that the shell is not wasting resources hanging around waiting for tmux to finish, when all it is going to do is then exit itself.